# DialogInterface vs View OnClickListeners

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, collision

Why can't I have both imports for `OnClickListener`. I have already `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;` but when I want to add `import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;` it gives me an error:

*The import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener collides with another import statement*

This is the reason why, for example, I have to write the full namespace of the `OnClickListener` when I need to implement a `DialogInterface` `OnClickListener`( i.e.

```
.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
```

Can anyone explain me this? I apologize if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't import two classes with the same name in the same file. If you import two classes with name `X` and you ask for an `X`, the compiler doesn't know which class you're referring to. There is a nice compromise in these situations. You can replace this import...

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
```

With this import...

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
```

Then when you need to refer to that particular interface, you can do something like this...

```
.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { ... })
```

This works because `DialogInterface` is an interface with a nested static interface named `OnClickListener`. This should be a little nicer on the eyes, and it solves the name collision problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume to think that's because some classes (like `AlertDialog`) work with the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` where the `OnClick` method takes two parameters :

> *Parameters*:
>       
> **dialog** - The dialog that received the click.
>       
> **paramAnonymousInt** - The button that was clicked (e.g. DialogInterface.BUTTON1) or the position of the item clicked.

Whereas the `OnClick` method from `View.OnClickListener` interface takes only one :

> *Parameters*:
>       
> **v** - The view that was clicked.